# Bash: stopping and filtering result process

Tags: bash, process, command

If i launch two terminals with xterm,i would like to know how filtering and stop the process on terminal 2 when the result of terminal 1 show me what i want.

Sample example: terminal 1 is a an active processus with some result inside
                terminal 2 is launched as an active processus too and will not stop until i have the result i want on terminal 1

then if active terminal 1 result show me what i want, terminal 2 is immediately stop.

How i can do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: [telepathic skills activated:] you need to close Term #2 window when the application launched in Term #1 finishes working and exits, right?

Comment: Can you make clear what does your termimal 2. You'll run on it only one know/unknow program, or many know/unknow programs ? Is that your program(s) on term 2 need to be launched interactively or can be in background ?

Comment: Terminal 2 is an interactive command, there is no specific link between term1 and 2 but the timelife of term2 depend of term1.For example, if term1 show me "test succesfull" then term2 is not longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to write into a file term 1 output, and searching your pattern from term 2.

## terminal 1

You can use `script` to log your shell into a file.

```
$ script --flush -c program_to_monitor /path/to/log/file #e.g. /tmp/term1.log
```

## terminal 2

This script search continously your pattern on term 1 log file, if founded, it send a SIGTERM to all process in term 2, if these proccesses are still alive after $delay, send a SIGKILL.

kill_tty.sh: (may have some caveats on BSD with `ps`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tty=$(tty)
delay=2
while true; do
  if grep "your_pattern" $term1_log 2>/dev/null ; then
    ps h -o pid --tty ${tty#/*/} | xargs kill #soft way
    sleep ${delay}s
    ps h -o pid --tty ${tty#/*/} | xargs -9 kill #hard way
  fi
done
```

Then lauch it on background

```
$ ./kill_tty.sh /path/to/log/file &
```

--
I'm sure they are better way to doing it but it's works.

Answer (score 0):

finaly resolve the problem by different way making a until loop from the commands i needed and receive the PID with

```
echo $! >/tmp/mypid.pid
```

And then kill it with

```
kill `cat /tmp/mypid.pid`
```